# How to define separate URL for assets (CSS, JS, Etc. ) like base_url(); in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got several answers of this question, like Define it in constant.php Etc.

However, It doesn't satisfy me and I guess other Codeigniter developers felt the same.

Can anyone help me out, I am repeating my question again,

How can we define another function which works same like base_url(); in Codeigniter, so that i can use it for my assets file (CSS, JS, Etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I like to deal with assets.

I create an helper called assets_helper in application/helpers/

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('css'))
{
    function css($nom)
    {
        return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . base_url() . 'assets/css/' . $nom . '.css " type="text/css" media="screen" />';
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('css_print'))
{
    function css_print($nom)
    {
        return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . base_url() . 'assets/css/' . $nom . '.css " type="text/css" media="print" />';
    }
}
//This is only the part that handle css for the example
```

Here is the full helper I use : http://pastebin.com/ujETEXJ4

After that, at the same level as index.php I create those folder :

```
|-Application
|-System
|-index.php
|-Assets
    |- css
    |- sass
    |- images
    |- js
```

Put all the css file you need in your new css folder. Same for js in /js, etc

In my application/config/autoload.php I add my new helper

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('assets', ...);
```

Finally, in the header of my page(s) :

```
<?php echo css('mycss'); ?> //I did not forgot the extension, it's how it works :)
```

Which will give at the end :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/assets/css/mycss.css" />
```

This way i can easly load any ressource in my code :

```
css('mycss'); //load css
css_print('mycss'); //css media="print"
js('myjs'); //load js
img('myimg.png') //img tag
img_url('myimg.png') //path to an image
```

**ALSO:**

To make it work, make sure you have correctly set your base_url in application/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/myawesomesite/";
//No index.php, don't forget the trailing slash!
```

Don't forget also to load the url helper in application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'assets');
```

Comment: **Thank you** to answer me, Thanks a lot. It Helps.